# Spring jackson deserialization and exception handling

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm building a REST api in Spring and I have problems with my exception handling. I want to  validate the full request and give information about the payload in one go.

Suppose my object is

```
public class StubJson {
    private BigDecimal bigDecimalField;
    @NotEmpty
    private String stringField;

    public void setBigDecimalField(BigDecimal bigDecimalField) { this.bigDecimalField = bigDecimalField; }
    public String setStringField(String stringField) { this.stringField = stringField; }
}
```

And my controller is

```
@RestController
public class StubController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/stub", method = POST)
    public void stub(@Valid @RequestBody StubJson stubJson) {}
}
```

The validation on this object is in a @ControllerAdvice that translates FieldError objects into translated errors for the end user.

```
@ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public List<ErrorJson> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {}
```

If I pass in this json

```
{"bigDecimalField": "text", "stringField": ""}
```

I want a response like this

```
[
  {
    "field": "stringField",
    "message": "Cannot be empty."
  },
  {
    "field": "bigDecimalField",
    "message": "Not a number."
  }
]
```

If I do this I get a

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException

on the BigDecimalField which only contains information about *only one* field. The only option I see is passing it in as a String or writing custom validation annotations. Is there an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: Your object conversion is failing even before it is ready to be validated. To achieve what you want requires your object needs to be created from your json request successfully

Comment: @ScanQR and how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller advice for this purpose. Declare a controller advice in your application, catch you expected exception, transform to you required response and return. Just remember controller advice will be applied to all of your controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    @ResponseBody public String typeMismatchException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse servletResponse, InvalidFormatException e ) {

        String yourResponse = "";
        return yourResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: My current implementation uses a @ControllerAdvice that catches MethodArgumentNotValidException which contains validation errors about multiple fields while this InvalidFormatException only contains information about one field. I'll update my question to make it more clear.